# React with Typescript: Render components from `map` function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have below `data` that I get from a json file and also import a utility function that picks out 5 random entities from an object Array in this case `data` array which has 30 entities.

I'm struggling to render the 5 random jockies  that are stored in `unique`. I'm fairly new to the ES6 syntax. How can I render the 5 jockeys from `unique`? Currently I'm getting

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'avatar_url' of undefined

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Jockey } from '../Jockey';
const data: JockeyArray[] = require('../../team.json');
import { getUniqueJockeys } from '../../utils/uniqueUtil';

interface JockeyArray {
    id: number;
    login: string;
    avatar_url: string;
}

interface State {
    nextRacers: string[];
    jockeys: JockeyArray[];
}

export class Race extends React.Component<Props, State> { 
    constructor(props: Props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            jockeys: data as JockeyArray[], 
            nextRacers: [],
        };
    }

    render() {
        
        if (this.props.startRandom) { // random selection
            
            // returns data array as 5 unique entities
            const unique = getUniqueJockeys(data);
            console.log(unique);//I can see my 5 randoms generated.
        
        return (
          <div>
            { unique.map((racer, index) => (       
                        // ??
                   <Jockey avatar={racer[index].avatar_url} />
              ))}
          </div>
        )
    }

}
```

**Definition of** `getUniqueJockeys`

```js
// Selecting 5 unique random jockeys
export const getUniqueJockeys = (anyArray: Array<object>) => {
    let uniqueArray = [];
    while (uniqueArray.length < 5) {
        const unique = Math.floor(Math.random() * anyArray.length);
        if (uniqueArray.indexOf(anyArray[unique]) > -1) {
            continue;
        }
        uniqueArray.push(anyArray[unique]);
    }
    return uniqueArray;
};
```

Comment: what is the definition of `getUniqueJockeys`

Comment: Ive just Added it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the definition of `getUniqueJockeys` to be more generic. If data is of type `JockeyArray[]` this should work (and you can use it for any values not just JockeyArray):

```
export const getUniqueJockeys = <T>(anyArray: Array<T>) => {
    let uniqueArray: T[] = [];
    while (uniqueArray.length < 5) {
        const unique = Math.floor(Math.random() * anyArray.length);
        if (uniqueArray.indexOf(anyArray[unique]) > -1) {
            continue;
        }
        uniqueArray.push(anyArray[unique]);
    }
    return uniqueArray;
};
```